# ListView Datapager not working When Session used instead of VeiwState

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I want to display list of clinics details in listview. From MasterPage Users selects the city & If he goes to clinincs page then list of hospitals display from selected city. Now If I use ViewState in my clinics page then It does not gets clinics data from selected city So what I have done I store City session & on clinics page I have used Session instead of ViewState Which is now working right but my datagaer stopped working. If I have to see another page from datapager then it doesn't switch over. Here is my code

MasterPage

```
Protected Sub locationSelector_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles locationSelector.TextChanged
    Session("masterLocation") = locationSelector.text
    Session("Data") = Nothing
End Sub
```

Clinics Page

```
Private Sub hospitals_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Try
        If Not Session("Data") Is Nothing Then
            hospitals.DataSource = Session("Data")
            hospitals.DataBind()
        Else
            Dim citySelector As Label = Page.Master.FindControl("locationPopupActivator")
            query = "select hospitalid, name, address, thumbnail, serviceID, mondayFrom, mondayTo, consultancyFees, city from hospitals Where city Like '" + citySelector.Text + "%'  and status = 'active'"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim table As New DataTable
            da.Fill(table)
            Session("Data") = table
            hospitals.DataSource = table
            hospitals.DataBind()
        End If

        'mainCount.Text = table.Rows(0)("countRows").ToString

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub DataPager1_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Try
        Dim table As DataTable = Session("Data")
        hospitals.DataSource = table
        hospitals.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Listview on ASPX

```
<asp:ListView ID="hospitals" runat="server" DataKeyNames="hospitalID" DataKey="hospitalID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        My Content
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div class="not-found">
            <p>
                Sorry! Selected Query Not Found</p>
            <center>
                <img src="images/not-found.jpg" /></center>
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </ul>
        <div class="datapager" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="10" PagedControlID="hospitals" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: We can discuss the solution but:

No concatenation of strings in query! Use Parameters.
No datatable in Session (or ViewState): reload from db.

Why do you bind hospitals in DataPager_PreRender?

Comment: @Emanuele what will be suitable for perfect output. Can you make changes in my code & post answer?

Comment: Can you change query code, please?
`Dim citySelector As String = Session("masterLocation")
query = "select hospitalid, name, address, thumbnail, serviceID, mondayFrom, mondayTo, consultancyFees, city from hospitals Where city Like @city  and status = 'active'"`

and add parameter @city, citySelector

Then move databinding in a ListBind function and recall it OnLoad or when you click a button

Comment: Give a look:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-in-ASPNet-ListView-control-using-DataPager-without-using-DataSource-control.aspx

Comment: @Emanuele here I have used pre Render event because from content page I am using master page control to select city. So from master page if I select city it shoud show only that city data in listview. So If I do it in pageload event then it doesn't takes city from masterpage because content page loads first & then master page loads so city goes blank in query

Comment: @Emanuele Also Instead of ViewState I have used session in listview which gets created on master page

Comment: @Emanuele will you please reply. I have set 100+ bounty on this post

Comment: It's ok for PreRender

Comment: It's better to reload your collection from Database instead of Session/Viewstate. Have you edited the query using parameters?

Comment: Have you read the article i linked? There is no databinding in Pager Pre Render

Comment: @Emanuele PLease tell me what is problem in my existing code? If I know where is a problem then it would be better to understand.

Comment: @Emanuele anyways I tried with the options you suggested but while changing city it doesn't refresh the listview which results in it is not showing the data of selected city.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what you have done. Can you remove DataPager1_PreRender? In the post i linked there isn't this code

Comment: I formatted your code samples to reduce the need to scroll horizontally. By the same token, I added a closing tag to the `img` element with `not-found.jpg`. I assumed that it was a typo, not an actual bug in the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working sample of your page:

### hospital.master

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="hospital.master.vb" Inherits="hospital_master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLockSel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="locationSelector">Locator Selector</asp:Label>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLocSel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="locationSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="locationPopupActivator" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### hospital.master.vb

```
Partial Class hospital_master
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Protected Sub locationSelector_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles locationSelector.TextChanged
        Session("masterLocation") = locationSelector.Text
        Session("Data") = Nothing
        locationPopupActivator.Text = locationSelector.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

### clinics.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/hospital.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="clinics.aspx.vb" Inherits="Clinics" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upHospitals" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
<asp:ListView ID="hospitals" runat="server" DataKeyNames="hospitalID" DataKey="hospitalID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%--My Content--%>
        <li>
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHospital" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("hospitalID", "~/hospital.aspx?id={0}") %>' Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div class="not-found">
            <p>
                Sorry! Selected Query Not Found</p>
            <center><%--<center>Is Deprecated Use div with CSS</center>--%>
                <img src="images/not-found.jpg" /></center>
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
            <%--Inside Update Panel dataPager should be outside paged control--%>
        <div class="datapager" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="10" PagedControlID="hospitals"><%-- ViewStateMode="Enabled"> this is default--%>
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

### clinics.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class Clinics
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Clinics_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Session.Remove("Data") 'init
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub hospitals_PagePropertiesChanging(sender As Object, e As PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs) Handles hospitals.PagePropertiesChanging
        DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
        hospitals.DataSource = GetData() 'Session("Data")
        hospitals.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub hospitals_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        hospitals.DataSource = GetData()
        hospitals.DataBind()
    End Sub
    Private Function GetData() As Data.DataTable
        Try
            If Session("Data") IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Session("Data")
            Else
                'This is MS SQL server. If you use MySQL then change types accordingly
                DataPager1.SetPageProperties(0, DataPager1.PageSize, False) 'reinit
                Dim citySelector As Label = Page.Master.FindControl("locationPopupActivator")
                Using con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClinicsCNN").ConnectionString)
                    Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select hospitalid, name, address, thumbnail, serviceID, mondayFrom, mondayTo, consultancyFees, city from hospitals Where city Like @city  and status = 'active'", con)
                    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = citySelector.Text & "%" 'same as Session("masterLocation")
                    Dim table As New Data.DataTable()
                    Dim da As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(table)
                    da.Dispose()
                    cmd.Dispose()
                    Session("Data") = table
                    Return table
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex) 'for debug purpose
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```

Do you accept this solution?

Comment: DataPager1 is not declared. It may be inaccecible due to it's protection level? this is the error.

Comment: Did you copy **all** code? Including `<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1"...` The copy is from working example.

Comment: Can you please configure it as per MySQL. I tried but there are some problem

Comment: change Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to MySqlConnection. do the same with sqlcommand, sqlparameter, sqladapter, and sqlDbType. I don't have mySQL. In your initial version you probably had some connection to mySQL.

Comment: I just don't understand this two line
 cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = citySelector.Text & "%"

Comment: commandType can be Text (as this case; this is default), Table, and StoredProcedure.  Parameters.Add adds new parameter and set its value. `& "%"` adds "any character to use with `like`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112350/discussion-between-alex-kudryashev-and-stupid-romeo).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after your comments here is my code that works for me:

```
Private Sub hospitals_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
Try 
            If Session("Data") Is Nothing Then
                Dim citySelector As Label = Page.Master.FindControl("locationPopupActivator")
                query = "select hospitalid, name, address, thumbnail, serviceID, mondayFrom, mondayTo, consultancyFees, city from hospitals Where city Like '" + citySelector.Text + "%'  and status = 'active'"
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim table As New DataTable
                da.Fill(table)
                Session("Data") = table
                hospitals.DataSource = table
                hospitals.DataBind()
            End If

            'mainCount.Text = table.Rows(0)("countRows").ToString
     Catch ex As Exception
       Response.Write(ex)
     End Try
End Sub

protected void hospitals_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            var datapager = ((DataPager)hospitals.FindControl("DataPager1"));
            datapager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
            hospitals.DataSource = Session["Data"];
            hospitals.DataBind();
            datapager.DataBind();
        }
```

I don't think you need `DataPager1_PreRender` method at all so probably you should remove it all together. You will need to attach new event to your list view: `OnPagePropertiesChanging="hospitals_PagePropertiesChanging"`. Sorry for code in c#, but I don't know VB very well ;)

Comment: Hi.. There is some problem with above code. Selected Datapager not working on first click. On secon click it gets highlighted but listview doesn't get refresh to show second page data

Comment: Second thing is selecting city from master page does not refresh listview data. Means by selecting city from master page needs to reloads page again to see that city data

Comment: Still problems remains the same

Comment: to be clarify I am using updatepanel & listview is under updatepanel.